# Avoid coarse sampling in Netdata custom dashboard Dygraphs charts

Tags: dygraphs, netdata

After upgrading from Netdata v1.37 to v1.44 I noticed that the Dygraphs charts on a custom dashboard were showing values older than 30 minutes with a straight line on data sampled at successive 30’ intervals. Scrolling the timeline restores full resolution, while clicking on “Chart Reset” goes back to the 30’ sampling. How can I have the timelines always plotted without coarse sampling?

Here is the chart’s definition and its appearance with and without interpolation.

```
   <div data-netdata="H.temperature"
      data-dygraph-title="Temperature"
      data-colors="#000080 #ff0000"
      data-after="-7200"
      data-before="0"
      data-height="10em"
      data-host="http://example.com:19999/"></div>
```

[image: Faulty graph with undesired interpolation]

[image: Ideal graph without interpolation]

I searched for a parameter to tweak by looking in the [Netdata documentation](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/miscellaneous/build-a-custom-dashboard-html-page), the [Dygraphs documentation](https://dygraphs.com/options.html#Data_20Line_20display)  and also for `dataattribute` in the [dashboard source code](https://github.com/netdata/netdata/blob/5b57fc441c40959514c4e2d0863be2e6a417e352/web/gui/dashboard.js), but didn't find a setting that seemed relevant.